# Broken install, dependency problems

Tags: python, debian

I wanted to upgrade python 3.5 to python 3.6 and because I was dumb and didn't run `apt-get remove python3` command I deleted the /usr/bin/python3 folder and now I have troubles installing another package.
The output of the error is : https://pastebin.com/ytrKUZRc

What I tried:

```
apt-get install python3
```

then when the error showed:

```
apt-get install -f
```

then

```
apt-get update
```

then

`dpkg --configure -a` then

`apt-get clean` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to solve the problem:

I deleted my source.list in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and generated a new one.

Then I ran the command `apt-get install python3`,

after it finished ran the command 
`apt-get -f install`

after everything was finished I ran the command 
`dpkg --configure -a`

and then the dependencies that were still broken I reinstalled them using the command

`apt-get install --reinstall dependency name`